# Create EventRecord object for NUnitTest

Tags: c#

I am about to write a EventLogReader to read an log Key-Management-Service EventLogs.
I don't have the option to test my Module because it'll run on another system and I don't got those EventLogs, only the XML content of an KMS-EventLog. Now my first idea was to create an own EventRecord object but the EventRecord class is an abstract class so this couldn't work. Now my question is, is there any way to create a EventRecord object and give my XML as input?

Comment: If `EventRecord` is an abstract class, why not extend it with your own `XmlEventRecord` class?

Comment: Sry if my questions are a bit "basic" but I'm relative new to C#. You mean I should create a new class and let it inherit from the EventRecord class? And need I to create a constructor for creating my object?

Comment: Yes, you have to create your class, the signature should be `class XmlEventRecord : EventRecord`. You can create a constructor if you want.

Comment: But if I let a class inherit from EventRecord there isn't a EventData/Data as Properties, which I need from the Event Log.

Comment: if you need properties from an `EventLog` object, then you can contain it in your XmlEventRecord :
`class XmlEventRecord : EventRecord{public EventLog MyEventLog {get; set}}` Then you have access to the properties by `xmlEventRecordInstance.MyEventLog.Property`

Comment: thank you for your help so far :) but now the next question is, I've got my XML saved in a string but how can I assign it now to my EventRecord?

Comment: So provide sample of your XML data